# npm Install : unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angularjs, aspnetboilerplate

Eveytime i try `npm install` i go this errors it is a boilerplate project is downloaded from : https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates.
I cant generate node_modules folder or start the server it s only on these boilerpart projects.any suggestions please im really tired.
here is a screenshot of the issue [issue Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE6sE.png)

also here is some versions of my environment:

```
npm: '8.3.1',node: '16.14.0',Angular CLI: 13.2.3



>   Package                      Version
> ------------------------------------------------------ @angular-devkit/architect    0.1302.3 (cli-only) @angular-devkit/core 
> 13.2.3 (cli-only) @angular-devkit/schematics   13.2.3 (cli-only) @schematics/angular          13.2.3 (cli-only)
```

Comment: I tried downloading their template and got the same error so it's not just you.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using asp.net? Angular and asp.net are not normally things I'd think of together.

Comment: @RockySims yes i have to .. it s actually not my choice it was the choice of the boss where im passing my internship for now :/ im like 11 hours searching on this issue cant find solution :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved ! .It was after running `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` before getting the error again,a bunch of warnings were shown telling me that the project must use

> `npm version : 6.11.0` and `node version >=14.0` so i had to switch into those older versions and it s done .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that template is expecting you to use [yarn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarn_(package_manager)) (not npm). You need to get yarn and then, in the terminal (instead of `npm install`), you do `yarn` to install the packages.

By the way, the tip off that it's expecting you to use yarn is the presence of the `yarn.lock` file.